# Restrict a sprite to a certain path?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I want to have a pac-man like game where the characters can move only in a certain path, preferably, with the option to have curved paths as well. What's the correct way to achieve that?

Comment: A collision-map somehow?

Comment: @bash.d Thanks. a) I mean _complete_ restriction, so I don't think that'll do. But: b) Are you referring to some built in mechanism or just calculating where the sprite is etc.?

Comment: XNA is rather low-level... You'll have to do much that stuff yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) to model this. The levels would be made up by a set of 2d-points and each player/bot would always be on his way from one point to another. Splines also handle curved paths.

In games Catmull-Rom splines are often used. If you google Catmull-Rom splines you can find theory, pseudo code or implementation of Catmull-Rom in just about any language.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the best way to go.

Comment: There's an API method in XNA, `Vector2.CatmullRom` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195227(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx)) ready to go (also available for `float` in `MathHelper`, and for `Vector3`).